# Safari doesn't produce a click event in <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a use case, where I need to open a new tab on users choice in select.

```
            <select ng-model="selected" ng-click="switchAction(data.id, selected)">
              <option disabled hidden selected value=""></option>
              <option value="run">1</option>
              <option value="edit">2</option> 
              <option value="deleteEnvironment">3</option>
              <option value="addSoftware">4</option>
              <option value="openLandingPage">5</option>
            </select>
```

Javascript:

```
        function switchAction(id, selected) {
        vm[selected](id);
        }

        vm.openLandingPage = function (id) {
        window.open(vm.landingPage + "?id=" + id);
        };
```

This code works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't in Safari. It could be partially solved, if I replace `ng-click` to `ng-change`. But then browser blocks a pop-up. Since, I render this code inside a grid cell, bootstrap's dropdown doesn't work either. I tried to put `ng-click` directly in option element, but it works only in firefox.

Is there any way to fix it?

Following plunker proofs that safari doesn't send a mouse-click event.

https://plnkr.co/edit/g3W2JLKxZFkzp1dGgrg4?p=preview

Comment: have You tried with `ng-input` ?

Comment: To use `ng-click` with select is not a good practice. You have to fix your pop up issue and use `ng-change`

Comment: @fedeghe do you mean this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-input ? It doesn't really render inside ag-grid cell. I also guess it's for input elements and not for select elements.

Comment: @Oleg right... makes sense what You say...exactly as would make sense if it could work with ng-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. With [angular-ui/bootstap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and `dropdown-append-to-body` option I was able to break throw the ag-grid border. Issue is finally fixed!